# compare time series data with ODE simulation

Tags: time-series, model, nonlinear

The same experiment was performed for 4 different initial conditions $(j=1,2,3,4)$. For each initial condition, there were 3 repetition $(i=1,2,3)$ of the experiment. I have 4 sets of data:

$X_{ij} = \big(X_i(t_1), X_i(t_2), X_i(t_3),X_i(t_4) \big)$, where $i = 1,2,3, j = 1,2,3,4$

in each set there is 3 repetition of the experiment.

I can simulate the data with ODE, so I will get 4 results for different initial conditions:

$Y_j = \big(Y(t_1), Y(t_2), Y(t_3), Y(t_4)\big)$.

I would like to compare my simulation with the data. What type of measure I should use in this case? I can compare $Y_j$ with each $X_{ij}$ but in this way I will get as a result 12 different distance. How to combine this together? I need the results to decide if to accept the ODE model with some parameters values or to reject.

Comment: To me, an "ODE" is an Ordinary Differential Equation, but I do not see how this would be related to the rest of the question. What do *you* mean by "ODE"?

Comment: By ODE I mean Ordinary Differential Equation. I am sampling parameters which are in my ODE, I am simulating path for time $t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4$. Then I want to compare how 'far' I am from the experimental data. If I am 'close enough' then I will accept the set of parameters used to simulate that path. If I am 'too far away' I will reject those parameters. Repeating this procedure will give me the distribution of accepted parameters.

Comment: Thank you. To answer your question well, we would need to know what the ODE is and what probability model you are assuming for the data and the initial conditions.  Could you include that information in the question?

Comment: Let say that I have following ODE: $\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y,\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a parameter. I solve (numerically) my ODE for four different initial conditions: $y_1(t=0) = c_1, y_2(t=0) =c_2, y_3(t=0) = c_3, y_4(t=0)=c_4 $. I am interested in times $t=t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4$, because I have data in those times. Therefore I have from my ODE simulation: $Y_1 = (y_1(t_1), y_1(t_2), y_1(t_3), y_1(t_4) )$ for initial condition $y_1(t=0)=c_1$; ... ; $Y_4 = (y_4(t_1), y_4(t_2), y_4(t_3), y_4(t_4) )$ for initial condition $y_4(t=0)=c_4$. All of those results are given some $\theta ~ Uniform(0,10)$.

Comment: Now I have following data: $X_1^i = (x_1^i(t_1), x_1^i(t_2), x_1^i(t_3), x_1^i(t_4))$ for initial condition $c_1$, where $i = 1,2,3$ because I have 3 repetition for each initial condition. In the same way I have data for $c_2, c_3$.

Comment: I am using ABC algorithm in order to find distribution of $\theta$ given the data. I have a problem with reject step. How should I decide if to reject, meaning what type of measure I should use to compare $Y$ with $X$. If I would have only one initial condition and one repetition for it I would compare this with my ODE simulation using simple Euclidean distance.

Comment: Please include that information in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use mean square error. [Decompose](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~tgd/classes/534/slides/part9.pdf) it into variance, bias and noise to gain insight in how to calibrate parameters.

Comment: Shall I just compute something like that? 1/3 sum_i {1/4 sum_j (Yj - Xij)^2}

Comment: Like averaging them over the 3 repetitions? I don't think you should do that, at least you need a really good reason to do that. You should calculate one mean square error for each configuration of parameters.